# How to create new Flow Resource with custom property editor

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

I have been looking at building a custom property editor for Apex Actions in Flows, following this:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_flow_custom_property_editor_action_example

I'm trying to recreate the searchable combobox that Salesforce uses in the standard Flow components, where you're able to search through the Flow variables to select the relevant variable you want.

I have been able to get all of this working, the only thing I am stuck on is what Event do I need to publish to be able to create a new resource?

Salesforce always have it as the first option in the list of selectable values:

[image: New Resource Image]

Is anyone aware of what I need CustomEvent I need to dispatch in order to have the modal appear?

Comment: To my knowledge, management of flow resources is not available. I actually posted an idea exchange idea for this exact thing when I observed it, but it doesn't look like it's gotten any traction.

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000OQq8VUAT/provide-events-for-resource-creation-and-updating-in-custom-property-editors

Answer (score 1):

How were you able to recreate the searchable combobox?

To send values back - you need to publish event once you make a selection:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-flow-custom-property-editor-interface.html

```
handleChange(event) {
if (event && event.detail) {
  const newValue = event.detail.value;
  const valueChangedEvent = new CustomEvent("Configuration_editor_input_value_changed", {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: false,
    composed: true,
    detail: {
      name: "senderName",
      newValue,
      newValueDataType: "String",
    },
  });
  this.dispatchEvent(valueChangedEvent);
}
```

}

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the question. Tim is asking how we can actually trigger the flow to create a new resource within the flow, not update the output value for the custom property editor